# Extracting data from RSA public key

Tags: c#, java, php, android, cryptography

I'm working on project that involves reading public key data used to sign Android APKs.  I am able to successfully extract the signatures as public keys.  When I look inside the binary pubkey files produced by this, I see some plain-text such as a name and a city.

**How can I safely extract this name/city information embedded inside the public key using PHP (or even Java or C#)?**  And hopefully do it in such a way that I know exactly what these fields are (i.e. not blindly grabbing text, but knowing which string is a city and which is a name)

*For clarification: I don't have the private key or a certificate file.  I'm currently not interested in signing or encrypting anything, I would just like to extract the plaintext inside the pubkey without using kludgy approaches like regex.*

**Update:**  Here's a sample (base64-encoded) public key from one of my APKs

```
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
```

Comment: Can you post an example of the "binary pubkey files produced by this"? Use Base-64 encoding to convert it to post-able text.

Comment: @FlyingStreudel - Regex can certainly be useful in many scenarios, but I don't think it's appropriate for this task :P

Comment: @erickson - Post has been updated.  I used this site to convert that into a binary file: http://www.motobit.com/util/base64-decoder-encoder.asp

Comment: Are you 100% certain you mean to say that the name/city data is "embedded in the public key"? I'd wager that what you're really after is a X509 certificate, which contains both the key _and_ metadata.

Comment: Colin this looks like a full x509 certificate to me.  Paste the base 64 string in: http://www.redkestrel.co.uk/cgi/decodeCert.cgi

Comment: @Kerrek & jglouie: Thanks for catching that :) In that case, I should definitely be able to use the x509-related PHP functions.

Comment: As a curious aside, Bruce Schneier seems to have a very low opinion of X.509. I think he said, "read the spec and weep". May I ask in which situation you would be presented with reliable name/city information in a certificate that you need to process?

Comment: @Kerrek SB: The public key / x509 certificate bytes are the most important, as I'll be comparing this information to other ones.  The name/city/etc information is mostly just to prove I'm doing things right and for visual display purposes.  That text data won't be relied upon for anything else.  I agree with Bruce that the data isn't reliable (as it can be arbitrarily set to anything by anybody), but a forger would end up with a different cert/key which is the important thing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The string you put in is a base 64 encoded x509 certificate, not simply a public key.

You'll need to parse the Distinguished Name fields to get the desired info.

Here's a C# example:

```
using System;
using System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates;

namespace Sample
{
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string base64EncodedX509 =
            "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";
        var rawBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(base64EncodedX509);

        X509Certificate cert = new X509Certificate(rawBytes);

        // Parse the distinguished name to get your desired fields

        Console.WriteLine(cert.Subject); // writes CN=Colin O'Dell, L=Narragansett, S=RI, C=US
        Console.WriteLine(cert.Issuer);  // writes CN=Colin O'Dell, L=Narragansett, S=RI, C=US
    }
}
}
```

Comment: This is perfect :)  After being informed I infact had a cert, I came up with a similar PHP solution to dump the data using `$dataAsArray = openssl_x509_parse(openssl_x509_read($pemFormattedCertString));`

Answer (score 1):

The "binary pubkey files produced by this" is an X.509 certificate.

Just about any platform has support for reading X.509 certificates, and creating a structure from them, from which you can reliably extract the "subject name," and often extended information that includes an email address or host name.

For example, if you have OpenSSL installed, use the following command:

```
openssl x509 -text -noout -inform der -in <yourfilehere>
```

You can extract specific fields with additional options. For example, adding `-subject` yields:

> subject= /C=US/ST=RI/L=Narragansett/CN=Colin O'Dell

Answer (score 0):

In php, I am not sure but maybe [this function](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.openssl-x509-parse.php) could be your friend.  There is a [whole section](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.openssl.php) of ssl related functions that could come in handy if you are playing with certificates.

Comment: Maybe, but I only have the public key and not a full certificate.  I skimmed through that function list earlier but wasn't able to find anything that specifically did want I wanted.  Perhaps I missed something?